# Appending a ID column to a data frame based on reference columns between two data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two data frames. One of the data frames contains a ID column, while the other does not. They do have the a column `NumID` that can be used as a reference, and a `date` column that can be used too. I would like to use the `NumID` and the first date for each `ID` in `df` to append a `ID` column into `df2`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)


date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2011"), dmy("25-01-2011"), by = "days"), 25)
ID <- rep(c("A","B", "C"), 25)
NumID <- rep(c("01000", "02000", "03000"), 25)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 ID,
                 NumID)


date2 <- c("01-01-2011", "2011-01-02", "2011-01-03")
NumID2 <- c("1000", "2000", "3000")
df2 <- data.frame(date = date2,
                 NumID = NumID2)
```

My expected output would look something like this:

```
ID2 <- c("A","B", "C")
expected <- data.frame(date = date2,
                  NumID = NumID2,
                  ID = ID2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple date formats in `date` column of 'df2'.  An option is to convert to `Date` class with `parse_date` and then do a join

```
library(parsedate)
library(dplyr)
df2$date <- as.Date(parse_date(df2$date))
# or use `lubridate::parse_date_time` with formats
# df2$date <- as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(df2$date, c("dmy", "ymd")))

left_join(df2, df)
```

-output

```
        date NumID ID
1 2011-01-01 00001  A
2 2011-01-02 00002  B
3 2011-01-03 00003  C
```

---

Or with a chain (`%>%`)

```
df2 %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(parse_date(date)), NumID = sprintf('%05s', NumID)) %>%
   left_join(df)
```

-output

```
        date NumID ID
1 2011-01-01 01000  A
2 2011-01-02 02000  B
3 2011-01-03 03000  C
```

Comment: You could do it in one `dplyr` chain using `mutate` right?

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your quick answer! I think it works great, but I made a slight modification to the question. The change is in the `NumID` columns for both data frames. One has a "0" in front of it and the other data frame does not. I was wondering if you might know a way around this.

Comment: @JohnHuang updated the answer.  You can either use `sprintf` or `stringr::str_pad` to add the 0s at the end.  In your example the column type is character, so i used `%05s'` if it is numeric, the fmt would be `%05d`